# VBA macro excel, calculating difference between two values based on previous variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add on to an existing VBA code for an excel project. 
I was looking for a VBA to find duplicate values in a column, and the result would be print in another column. For example if User1 is entered twice in a column, the second time it is entered - there would be "duplicate" in the next column.

```
Sub DuplicateFinder()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    LastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    For iCntr = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
            matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & LastRow), 0)
            If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
                Cells(iCntr, 2) = "Duplicate"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Is it possible to modify this, then when a duplicate is found, it will check another column for difference between two values.

So if I had a:

```
 A      |    B    |    C    |    D
 user1                11
 user2                11
 user1    duplicate   12      "error"
```

I would like the macro to say "error" if the difference between the two values is =< 6

Comment: Do you have to use VBA? a simple formula can do the trick. Let me know and I will post it.

Comment: What happens if there are more than two instances of user1 in column A?  Which two values should be compared?

Comment: @Pucho If you can do this with a formula, please do. It didn't occur to me that it could be done in such way.

Comment: @J. Garth if there is more than one instances, it should compare the values of the last found duplicate, and the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the difference between most recent cell and the match is <= 6:

```
If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
   Cells(iCntr, 2) = "Duplicate"
   If Cells(iCntr, 3) - Cells(matchFoundIndex, 3) <= 6 Then
      Cells(iCntr, 4) = "Error"
   End If
End If
```

If you want the absolute difference:

```
If Abs(Cells(iCntr, 3) - Cells(matchFoundIndex, 3)) <= 6 Then
```

Comment: Thank you. I just added this to my first code and it does what I needed

Answer (score 0):

for a more general approach I'd go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateFinder()
    Dim user As Variant

    With Sheets("duplicates") '<--| change "duplicates" to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A range from row 1 (header) down to the one corresponding to last column A not empty row
            For Each user In GetUsers(.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)) '<-- get unique users starting from 2nd row downwards and loop through them
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, user) > 1 Then HandleUser .Cells, user '<--| if more then one current user occurrences then "handle" it
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Sub HandleUser(rng As Range, user As Variant)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iCell As Long, refvalue As Long

    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=user '<--| filter column A cells with current 'user'
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<-- reference filtered cells, skippinh headers
            refvalue = .Cells(, 2).Value '<--| retrieve first occurrence value from cell two columns to the right
            For Each cell In .Cells '<--| loop through filtered cells
                If iCell > 0 Then '<--| start handling occurrences form the 2nd one on
                    cell.Offset(, 1) = "Duplicate" '<--| mark it as duplicate
                    If cell.Offset(, 2) - refvalue > 6 Then cell.Offset(, 3) = "error" '<--| place "error" if two cells to the right from current 'user' has a value greater then first occurrence value + 6
                End If
                iCell = iCell + 1 '<--| update user occurrences counter
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function GetUsers(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In rng
            .Item(cell.Value) = cell.Value
        Next cell
        GetUsers = .keys
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this code, but all it did was found the duplicates

Comment: It's tested code. So step through it and use Immefiate Window to see if relevant variables values or object properties match what you expect them to be